# Plot for big x numbers

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, big-numbers

I want to make a plot of data with big values by x.
My code is this

```
myList = {{10^15, 1}, {10^15 + 1, 1.2}, {10^15 + 2, 1.5}, {10^15 + 3, 1.1}}
ListPlot[myList, PlotRange -> {{10^15, 10^15 + 3}, {0, 2}}]
```

but when I get a plot, it looks like x always the same
[image]

and look like mathematica ignores my PlotRange and make it from 0 to 2*10^15.

How can I force mathematica to make x axis from 10^15 to 10^15 + 3?

UPDATE1

I also have similar problem if I want to plot function like this

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,10^15, 10^15 + 3}]
```

[image]

of course if I convert it to the Table and use solution from Simon Rochester's answer, it will work.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[Transpose[Table[{x,Sin[x]}, {x,10^15, 10^15 + 3, 0.1}]] - {10^15, 0}], PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

but is there any way to do it directly with Plot[]?

I put this [example to mathematica cloud](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/179ec7b0-a2bc-4529-ba68-487bf092d785). I hope it will work for everyone.

UPDATE2

I can do it with Plot of function like this

```
Plot[Sin[10^15+x],{x,0, 3}]
```

But somehow graph looks strange :)
[image]

Comment: Interestingly, for me the boundary for this breaking appears to be at `4.398046511103750*^13 `, which doesn't have much numerical relevance as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, it is strange. Might be it is a mathematica bug.

Comment: At first glance this looks like a bug in `Graphics`, but perhaps it is merely a design limitation or I misunderstand.  e.g. `Graphics[Point[myList], PlotRange -> {{10^15, 10^15 + 3}, {0, 2}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True]` also does not work "correctly."

Comment: that last jagged plot is a precision problem, try `Plot[Sin[10^15 + x], {x, 0, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

Comment: @george2079 Yes, thanks. Your example works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Might I suggest not making a plot like that? Whatever information that you are trying to get across will likely be clearer if you plot with x-values relative to $10^{15}$ and note that in the axes label or the caption:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[Transpose[myList] - {10^15, 0}], PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you really want big numbers on the axis, you could put them there by hand:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[Transpose[myList] - {10^15, 0}], PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}, 
  Ticks -> {Join[Table[{i, i + 10^15}, {i, 0, 3, 3}], Table[{i, "", {.01, 0}}, {i, 0, 3, .5}]], Automatic}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow. It is very good answer.
But what can I do if I need to plot some function like this:
Plot[Sin[x],{x,10^15, 10^15 + 3}]
?

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize for the people who will search it.
There are 3 solutions:

1. Like suggested by Simon Rochester

   myList = {{10^15, 1}, {10^15 + 1, 1.2}, {10^15 + 2, 1.5}, {10^15 + 3, 1.1}}
   ListPlot[Transpose[Transpose[myList] - {10^15, 0}], PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}]

[image]

2. Solution for problem Plot[Sin[x],{x,10^15, 10^15+3}] based on Simon Rochester's answer

   ListPlot[Transpose[Transpose[Table[{x,Sin[x]}, {x,10^15, 10^15 + 3, 0.1}]] - {10^15, 0}], PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-1, 1}}]

[image]

3. Solution with plot

   Plot[Sin[10^15+x], {x,0,3}]

[image]

and to avoid steps

```
Plot[Sin[10^15+x],{x,0,3}, WorkingPrecision->20]
```

[image]

and with proper ticks (from Simon Rochester's example)

```
Plot[Sin[10^15+x],{x,0, 3}, Ticks -> {Join[Table[{i, i + 10^15,{0.02,0}}, {i, 0, 3, 1}], Table[{i, "", {0.01, 0}}, {i, 0, 3, .1}]], Automatic},WorkingPrecision->20]
```

[image]

All problem and solution are available [here](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/179ec7b0-a2bc-4529-ba68-487bf092d785). It is mathematica cloud, I am not sure how long it will be available.